# How to include JavaFX Chart into existing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, charts

I have two classes, the first contains the existing GUI and the second is for creating a line chart.
Now my question is how can I include the created Chart in my existing GUI without creating a new Window like it is now?
Chart Creating Method:

```
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {
    s.setTitle("JavaFX Realtime Chart Demo");

    //defining the axes
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(); // we are gonna plot against time
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,10,1);
    xAxis.setLabel("Time/s");
    xAxis.setAnimated(false); // axis animations are removed
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");
    yAxis.setAnimated(false); // axis animations are removed

    //creating the line chart with two axis created above
    final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Realtime JavaFX Charts");
    lineChart.setAnimated(true); // disable animations

    //defining a series to display data
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName("U/s");
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series2.setName("km/h");
    // add series to chart
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series,series2);


    // setup scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
    s.setScene(scene);

    // show the stage        
    s.show();

    // this is used to display time in HH:mm:ss format
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    // setup a scheduled executor to periodically put data into the chart
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    // put dummy data onto graph per second
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        // get a random integer between 0-10



        wert = G.gebeInt();
        wert_2 = G.gebeV();
        // Update the chart
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // get current time
            Date now = new Date();
            // put random number with current time

            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(simpleDateFormat.format(now), wert));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(simpleDateFormat.format(now), wert_2));

            if (series.getData().size() > WINDOW_SIZE) {
                series.getData().remove(0);
            }
            if (series2.getData().size() > WINDOW_SIZE) {
                series2.getData().remove(0);
            }
        });
    }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

I use Swing for the GUI and JavaFX for creating the charts, in this case a LineChart.

Comment: Without seeing an example of your code (see [mre]) we can't give any specific advice. In general, however, you just need to add the `LineChart` to a parent in your current window. Also, you've tagged both Swing and JavaFX—are you actually using both?

Comment: I use Swing for the existing GUI and JavaFX for creating the charts.

Comment: The problem is, that the GUI and the Chart is in two separated classes.

Comment: To embed JavaFX into a Swing GUI you need to use a [`JFXPanel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.htmll); don't subclass `Application` for this. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: I linked to a tutorial. I can't give a proper answer because I don't know how you're trying to link things together. If you have things in different classes then you'll need to add the ability to communicate between them. However, it looks like you just need to create the `LineChart`, add it to a `JFXPanel`, then add the `JFXPanel` somewhere in your Swing GUI—a separate class might not even be necessary.